# Spark Windows error when executing toDF

Tags: windows, hadoop, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am running Spark 2.0 on a Windows 10 64bit VM. I am able to run the spark-shell fine and can execute any of the methods in Scala related to RDD's. When I enter the following (*I have verified that the issue occurs on the toDF method*):

```
val df = Seq(("one",1), ("two", 2), ("three", 3)).toDF("word", "count")
```

I get an exception that starts with this information:

> 16/09/09 00:04:10 WARN General: Plugin (Bundle) "org.datanucleus.api.jdo" is already registered. Ensure you dont have multiple JAR versions of the same plugin in the classpath. The URL "file:/C:/Spark/jars/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar" is already registered, and you are trying to register an identical plugin located at URL "file:/C:/Spark/bin/../jars/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar."
>   16/09/09 00:04:10 WARN General: Plugin (Bundle) "org.datanucleus.store.rdbms" is already registered. Ensure you dont have multiple JAR versions of the same plugin in the classpath. The URL "file:/C:/Spark/jars/datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar" is already registered, and you are trying to register an identical plugin located at URL "file:/C:/Spark/bin/../jars/datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar."
>   16/09/09 00:04:10 WARN General: Plugin (Bundle) "org.datanucleus" is already registered. Ensure you dont have multiple JAR versions of the same plugin in the classpath. The URL "file:/C:/Spark/bin/../jars/datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar" is already registered, and you are trying to register an identical plugin located at URL "file:/C:/Spark/jars/datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar."
>   16/09/09 00:04:13 WARN ObjectStore: Failed to get database default, returning NoSuchObjectException
>   16/09/09 00:04:13 WARN Hive: Failed to access metastore. This class should not accessed in runtime.
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getAllDatabases(Hive.java:1236)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.reloadFunctions(Hive.java:174)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.(Hive.java:166)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:503)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.(HiveClientImpl.scala:171)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)...

Here are my environment variables:

- SPARK_HOME  | C:\Spark
- HADOOP_HOME | C:\Spark
- JAVA_HOME   | C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101

I have the winutils.exe in the C:\Spark\bin folder

As additional information, when I execute the spark-shell command I notice this statement, but my research indicates it does not matter.

> 16/09/09 00:36:32 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable